# trying to show image or file posted on API asp.net core hosted on linux

Tags: c#, linux, api, file, asp.net-core

I'm uploading files to a folder that i have verified are working fine means files are uploading fine. but i want to show these to front end means i want to access the by URl. but don't why i'm not able to. UR is correct but it always show 404 error.

Then to verify i uploaded one text file but again, it was showing 404 error.

could anyone confirm where i m missing something, i'm hosting the asp.net core API 3.0 on linux first time. i've tried to google for same but didn't get anything which works form. please help me.

Comment: Error 404 is not found.  So the url path is not valid or you do not have the credential to access the url.

Comment: @jdweng, i have verified all file exists on same path that's why i'm not getting why it is showing 404 error.. do i need to make any specific setting?

Comment: You need to share more details such as the URL of the file you are trying to access, the path of the file on the server etc...

Comment: How did you verify?  On linux machine or from the remote machine?  Are you using a password to do the uploads?  It may be a credential issue.  Did you check in linux the permission of the file(s) and parent folder(s).

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, check my updated question

Comment: @jdweng, yes, i have verified all these things before posting here.

Comment: Can you browse to the file in a windows explorer (or IE).  You can use File://servername/folder

Comment: how do you set the url ? if possible , please include the code also. It is 404 error so the reasons may be what @jdweng mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: The URL is an IP address (or host name) followed by the path where the upload is stored.  The path must have the credentials set properly.  So I first manually test the upload before trying in code.  You can use a windows explorer using the same URL ftp:\\ (instead of http, the server may require secure mode ftps) or from cmd.exe >FTP HOST.  the login and use CD (change directory).